# Give getBoundingClientRect values to element

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, foreach

I'm tryin' to duplicate css values of videos and imgs (x, y, height, weidth) on span elements. For this I use getBoundingClientRect, but it only duplicates values of the first element of my videos/imgs elements.

```js
var projectEA = document.getElementById("project-ea");
var medias = projectEA.querySelectorAll("video, img");
console.log(medias);

medias.forEach(function(media){

  var getObj = media.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(getObj);
  var legends = projectEA.getElementsByClassName("item__legend");
  var legendsArray = [].slice.call(legends);
  
  legendsArray.forEach(function(legend){
      legend.style.top = (getObj.top + getObj.height) + 'px';
      legend.style.left = getObj.left + 'px';
      legend.style.width = getObj.width + 'px';
      legend.style.height = getObj.height + 'px';
  });
  
});
```

```html
<section id="project-ea" class="project">

    <span class="item__legend">EA13 - Version mobile</span>
    <span class="item__legend">EA13 - Version desktop</span>
    <span class="item__legend">EA13 - Texture</span>
    <span class="item__legend">EA12 - Texture</span>
    <span class="item__legend">EA12 - Version desktop</span>

    <div class="project__video">
      <video width="100%" class="video-js" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted>
          <source
          src="ea-mobile.mp4"
          type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="project__video">
      <video width="100%" class="video-js" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted>
          <source
          src="ea13.mp4"
          type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="project__photo">
      <img src="ea-photo1.jpg" class="half-img-left" alt="Electro Alternativ Texture"/>
      <img src="ea-photo2.jpg" class="half-img-right" alt="Electro Alternativ Texture"/>
    </div>
    <div class="project__video">
      <video width="100%" class="video-js" preload="auto" autoplay loop muted>
          <source
          src="electroalternativ.mp4"
          type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>

</section>
```

I wish first span element gets first media values, second span gets second media values, etc..

Comment: Your js is fine. Span is an inline element, you need to update its display value to 'inline-block' or 'block' in the CSS

Comment: @sol I already did it. There might be a problem in my js, because all my span elements get the same values (the values of the last video elem).

Comment: Well you are looping over _all_ span elements each time, inside your loop over the media elements … Stop doing that, and access one specific span via its _index_ in the collection instead.

Comment: @misorude You're right, but I can't figure it out.. Should I loop with a classic for outside the forEach ?

Comment: You should not _nest_ loops here in the first place (the method to access items in a collection via index exists, so no second loop necessary) - go check how the loop iteration counter is passed to the forEach callback function, and then simply use that counter to access the _correct_ span element.